# Android - Forms

Tags: android, forms

on my app a have a form which contains 2 fields and a save button.

What do i need at the end of my onClick to return the cursor back to the first field.

i have this to clear them both

```
        txtData.setText("");
        txtData2.setText("");
```

but the cursor always stays on the bottom field

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried progamatically calling [requestFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29) on the view you want to have focus after the user clicks on your save button? For instance, you could in your onClick method do something like:

```
public void onClick(View){
  //do other stuff like saving and clearing the fields
  //then request the focus be switched back to the first text field.
  txtData.requestFocus();
}
```